# Is there a one liner in javascript to use an array of string as an object path?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-6

let's say I have the following array :

```
let path = ['foo','bar']
```

And I have this item :

```
let item = {
    faa: 'whatever',
    foo: {
        bar: 'hello there', //general kenobi
        bor: 'nope'
    }
}
```

I want to access "hello there" using something looking like :

```
item[path] or item.path or item[path.join(".")]
```

You get the idea, is this doable and if yes, how ?
(of course what is written in this question does not work)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can do

```
let target = path.reduce((o, t)=> o ? o[t] : undefined, item)
```

This one-liner is designed to ensure there won't be any error if there's no match: it just returns `undefined`.

Demonstration:

```js
let item = {
    faa: 'whatever',
    foo: {
        bar: 'hello there', //general kenobi
        bor: 'nope'
    }
}
let path = ['foo','bar']
let target = path.reduce((o, t)=> o ? o[t] : undefined, item)
console.log(target)
```

Comment: Yup, just tested it myself, it does work ! Thank you good sir, accepting your answer in 10 minutes when allowed by SO

Comment: I use this exact pattern in one of my applications to get configuration items: https://github.com/Canop/miaou/blob/master/libs/Miaou.js#L34

Comment: This will be used for a very similar purpose !

Answer (score 0):

You can also use the third party libraries like Lodash.

then you can use Lodash get like this:

```
import {get} from Lodash

var x=get(item,path.join("."))
```

The good thing about it is if the item doesn't have 'foo', you won't get an error. It works like safe navigation on an object.